CD pipelines not triggered anymore
We split our CI/CD pipelines in a CI and CD pipeline.
The CI pipeline is called "VABApolloDataModel-Export", we only have a main branch.
We currently had it set like this in our CD pipeline, worked for weeks :
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'CI-Pipeline'
    source: 'VABApolloDataModel-Export'
    trigger:
      branches:
        - main

Also tried this
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'CI-Pipeline'
    source: 'VABApolloDataModel-Export'
    trigger: true

And tried this
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'CI-Pipeline'
    source: 'VABApolloDataModel-Export'
    trigger:
      branches:
        - '*'

None of these options are triggering the CD pipeline once the CI one is finished.
I checked for trigger issues in DevOps and it says that there are none.
Not sure what is causing this problem and why it did work properly before :-(
Any idea's ?
Regards,
Sven


None of these options are triggering the CD pipeline once the CI one is finished.

I suggest that you can check the following settings of CD YAML Pipeline.
You can check the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds of the pipeline in pqr project(Navigate to Edit -> Triggers -> Yaml -> Get sources).

You need to make sure that the Yaml file in the default branch contains the correct Resource pipeline trigger.
Pipeline will use the resources trigger in the default branch of the YAML pipeline
If no, you need to change the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds to the correct branch.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: The pipeline default branch
If it still not work, you can consider setting the trigger in CD Pipeline Trigger UI.
You can navigate to Edit -> Triggers  and set the Build Completion trigger in Azure DevOps UI.

In this case, when the CI Pipeline is completed, it also can trigger the CD Pipeline.
